# Mysql Order By month days

Tags: mysql

```
01-09-2016   01,September 2016              12

02-09-2016   02,September 2016              21

03-09-2016   03,September 2016              19

04-09-2016   04,September 2016              15

05-09-2016   05,September 2016              19

23-08-2016   23,August 2016                 21

24-08-2016   24,August 2016                 22

25-08-2016   25,August 2016                 24

26-08-2016   26,August 2016                 24

27-08-2016   27,August 2016                 18
```

**I want result like below**

```
23-08-2016   23,August 2016                 21

24-08-2016   24,August 2016                 22

25-08-2016   25,August 2016                 24

26-08-2016   26,August 2016                 24

27-08-2016   27,August 2016                 18

01-09-2016   01,September 2016              12

02-09-2016   02,September 2016              21

03-09-2016   03,September 2016              19

04-09-2016   04,September 2016              15

05-09-2016   05,September 2016              19
```

Comment: Add the query you have tried

Answer (score 0):

**You should change the date format. Period.**

The proper date format your database supports is chosen not by a whim but for the very reason of making the proper sorting and comparison possible.

Therefore, change your values format to `2016-09-01` and the field type to `date`. And you will never have not a single problem neither with sorting nor comparison nor any date conversions.